# Converting geographic coordinates from GEOSTAT to lat and lng

Tags: python, latitude-longitude, geo

I've found an interesting [datasource of European Population](https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/web/gisco/geodata/reference-data/population-distribution-demography/geostat) which I think could help me in achieving such a map:

[image]

The source document `GEOSTAT_grid_POP_1K_2011_V2_0_1.csv` looks like this:

`| TOT_P | GRD_ID        | CNTR_CODE | METHD_CL | YEAR | DATA_SRC | TOT_P_CON_DT | 
|-------|---------------|-----------|----------|------|----------|--------------| 
| 8     | 1kmN2689E4337 | DE        | A        | 2011 | DE       | other        | 
| 7     | 1kmN2689E4341 | DE        | A        | 2011 | DE       | other        |`

Geographic coordinates look to be coded in the `GRD_ID` column this document indicates [Appendix1_WP1C_production-procedures-bottom-up.pdf](https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/cros/sites/crosportal/files/Appendix1_WP1C_production-procedures-bottom-up.pdf):

> Grid cell identification codes are based on grid cell’s lower left-hand corner coordinates truncated by grid
>   cell size (e.g. 1kmN4534E5066 is result from coordinates Y=4534672, X=5066332 and the cell size 1000)

I thought I could get lat and long by parsing the strings. For example in Python:

```
import re
string = "1kmN2691E4341"
lat = float(re.sub('.*N([0-9]+)[EW].*', '\\1', string))/100
lng = float(re.sub('.*[EW]([0-9]+)', '\\1', string))/100

print lat, ",", lng
```

> Output 26.91 , 43.41

but it makes no sense, it does not correspond to a location in Europe !

It may be that it refers to a geographic coordinate system I'm not aware of.

Comment: Frome one PDF:GRD_ID     Identification code of the grid cell (lower left- hand corner) according to INSPIRED (http://www.efgs.info/wp-content/uploads/geostat/1a/GEOSTAT1A-final-report.pdf )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Viktor's comment, I found out that the coordinate system used in my file was `EPSG:3035`

Based on python's implementation of `Proj4`, I could achieve a convincing result with the following code:

```
#! /usr/bin/python
# coding: utf-8

import re
from pyproj import Proj, transform

string = "1kmN2326E3989"

x1 = int(re.sub('.*[EW]([0-9]+)', '\\1', string))*1000
y1 = int(re.sub('.*N([0-9]+)[EW].*', '\\1', string))*1000

inProj = Proj(init='EPSG:3035')
outProj = Proj(init='epsg:4326')

lng,lat = transform(inProj,outProj,x1,y1)
print lat,lng
```

> Output : 43.9613760836 5.870517281